# organize file paths in c#

Tags: c#

is there a way if organizing paths depending on which one is more towards the root. For example if I have the paths:

```
"C:\someFolder\program files\b"
"C:\someFolder\X"
"C:\Z"
"C:\someFolder\program files\a"
```

then I will like to sort them as:

```
"C:\Z"
"C:\someFolder\X"
"C:\someFolder\program files\a"
"C:\someFolder\program files\b"
```

I am actually trying to create a tree view and that's why I want to sort them like that.

Comment: i can´t find a pattern in your described sort order. I think you want to change "C:\someFolder\program files\a" and "C:\someFolder\program files\b"

Comment: @Jehof: Why should he do that? The order seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Maybe its a little bit late but for me its a mix of descending and ascending sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
files.OrderBy(x => x.Split('\\').Length).ThenBy(x => x)
```

Comment: +1 But: 1) Shouldn't we use `System.IO.Path.PathSeparator` instead of '\\' 2) Empty strings need to be removed from the `Split` with .Where(s=>s!="") since it is legal to have several continuous separator in a path and they are semantically equivalent to a single one.

Comment: @Coincoin Another solution for point 2 would be to specify the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` split option for `Split`.

Comment: @Etienne - Thanks for the trick. I can't beleive all that time I filtered them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a

> pathName.Split('/').Length

on the path to get the number of levels deep, then sort on that number.